# netCDF4 has no module Dataset using Anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, netcdf4

I am using Anaconda to manage my environments, and I have a strange problem with netCDF4.

I have several Jupyter notebooks in my environment that I've been using with netCDF4, no problem at all.  I'm only interested in reading NetCDF files, so I'm only really using the Dataset.

Now I'm implementing the algorithm from my Jupyter notebooks in a Python package, and I get this error (in VS  Code):

> No name 'Dataset' in module 'netCDF4'

I can see that it's installed in Anaconda Navigator and if I try to do a pip install it reports that netcdf4 is already installed and all dependencies are met.

I've read similar-sounding posts here and they do not solve my problem.

In response to a comment, the error is where I import Dataset:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

This also gives the error:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
salinity_data = nc.Dataset(<file name etc...>)
```

The code completion does not show anything in the netCDF4 package other than some "_" prefixed variables.

I'm using Python 3.8.12 and I am using the correct virtual environment that I set up with Anaconda.

Comment: "*in a Python package*" - and the import error happens if you do what? Which Python interpreter is VSCode using? By the way, if you use Anaconda, don't mix in pip installs, that creates a mess in my experience. Either use pip *or* conda, not both at the same time.

Comment: I've added some info to the initial question in response to the above comment.

Comment: hm not really sure what is the problem here. did you try [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) to load the nc file? does this work? (I find that to be more convenient than netCDF4 anyway...)

Comment: I just tried switching my virtual environment to the one I created for another project that also uses the netCDF4 package.  No error when using that environment... so I cloned it. Now I have the same environment with a different name.  Jupyter works great but I get exactly the same error in VS Code.  I'm beginning to wonder if I have inadvertently redefined netCDF4 somewhere.

Comment: I just looked at the docs for xarray and it seems to depend on netCDF4 so that probably won't work.  I will try it if I can't track this down.

Comment: Clearing out the __pycache__ folder didn't help.

Comment: The code will run, so this looks like a pylint problem.

Comment: Normally, the linter should not interfere with code execution... did you try xarray? Another IDE maybe? I found VS Code to be a bit difficult to get correctly configured for Python

Comment: I tried xarray, but just using the h5netcdf package by itself did what I needed without adding another dependency to the project (xarray needs either netrcdf or h5netcdf installed to work).  Thanks for the pointer to xarray though!

Comment: I am using xarray now with h5netcdf and it really is a great toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is coming from pylint, not the Python interpreter (see comments above).

The code will run fine, so the issue is with pylint and the configuration.  I can suppress the error by:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset #pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
```

This will do for now, but at some point, I'd like to figure out why pylint is reporting this.

I have also found a package that works better for what I want to do wth the netCDF files:

https://github.com/h5netcdf/h5netcdf

This doesn't have all the hidden dependencies that netCDF4 does, and has a "legacyapi" that is a drop-in replacement for the netcdf package:

```
import hfnetcdf.legacyapi as nc
my_data = nc.Dataset('my_data_file.nc', 'r')
```